# The type or namespace name 'DomainServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-framework-version

I am getting the following error in my VS 2015 project :

.net framework 4.6

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'DomainServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Also  the following dlls are missing under the References folder :

```
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will need to install the WCF RIA Services Toolkit separately because DomainServices is not apart of the standard WCF library.

Here is the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28357) to download the WCF RIA Services Toolkit

Comment: downloaded the WCF RIA servies toolkit and installed still I am getting the same error. Is there somethign I add under References folder.

Comment: At that point, I'm pretty sure that you're supposed to remove the reference, and then re-add it. I think it's under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Silverlight\". That's where the DLLs should be.